# get dynamically loaded html using alamofire + swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, alamofire

I am trying to request a website's html code and use it in an app in Xcode (Swift 3.0) and the pod Alamofire. In the html code online, the data contents that I want to scrape are in a div class that returns data from an Events calendar, in the form of a javascript web plugin. Since the website is not static, when I request the html and print the resulting response as a string, the data I want is not contained in the string. A message appears that says:

`<noscript>Your browser must support JavaScript to view this content. 
    Please enable JavaScript in your browser settings then try again. 
    <a href="https://www.trumba.com">Events calendar powered by Trumba</a>
    </noscript>`

My code using Alamofire looks like:

```
func downloadCalendar(){
    Alamofire.request(urlString).responseString { (AlamofireResponse) in
        print(AlamofireResponse.result.value!)
    }
}
```

The urlString is a variable for the actual webpage's url. 
Is there a way to get all of the html that appears in the html online into Xcode using Alamofire? If it's not possible with Alamofire is there another way to do this using Swift?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to accomplish a similar thing, unfortunately to no avail...

It seams AlamoFire grabs the first response it gets....

There is a workaround - use UIWebView:

```
static let webView = UIWebView()
self.webView.loadRequest(URLRequest.init(url: URL.init(string:"http://example.com")!)

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+10.0) {[unowned self] in
        if let html = self.webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.outerHTML") 
        {print(html)}
}
```

Where `10.0` is the approx number of seconds required for javascript to finish loading the webpage data.

However since: it's not thread safe, you must use a singleton webView,
import UIKit and can't do it in the background - it's far from the perfect solution...

It might be easier to setup a proxy webserver in between to do the parsing for you.

Cheers!